# Passing a method from another class

Tags: java, android

I want to call a method from one class to another, don't know if that's possible without extends the class that contains the method. I've tried to import the package, that way I thought the method should be allow to use since it's a public method but that was not sucesfull..

tried to use this [link](http://thedevelopersinfo.wordpress.com/2009/10/15/passing-data-between-activities-in-android/) as reference, but I didn't understand it (since is an app for android..)

A pseudo-code to exemplify

```
class 1
class 2

class 2:

import package.class 1;


class 1.this.method();  -> Error: No enclosing instance of the type class 1 in is acessible in scope
```

Comment: The link you referenced details passing data between activities, do you want to pass data or access a method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other way may be,  create object for other class and then invoke the method on that object. Something like below.

```
new ClassA().yourMethod();
```

Comment: why does it needs ClassA().yourMethod(); instead of new ClassA.yourMethod(); ? it worked as you said but the second way I've tried says that classA.yourMethod can't be resolved as a type

Comment: if your accessing instance method (means methods which are not static), it should be through instance of the class. So, new ClassA() is instance of ClassA. The other syntax ClassA() is not a valid syntax. Java don't know what to do with statement, so it just throws compile time error.

Answer (score 0):

You need an instance of object from class 1 to invoke that method, or if it doesn't need an instance - you can declare it as static and then you can write 1.method().

Answer (score 0):

In java you 2 main ways to do that:

1. `Class2 extends Class1` and then you can call all `protected` or `public` methods of class 1.
2. Get an instance of class1 inside class2:

   ```
   Class1 c1 = new Class1();
   c1.someMethod();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the method without creating an instance of the class then make it `static`:

```
Class1
{
...
    public static void method1() {doSomething;}
}

Class2
{
    public class2()
    {
        Class1.method1(); //should be fine
    }
}
```

edit: If you want to pass data between `Activities` that is slightly different.  Generally you do something like `startActivityForResult()` and then retrieve the return value, or use `Intents` like so:

[How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android)

Comment: unable to do that cause I use a constructor that can't be static, but thanks anyway haha wil try another time

Comment: @VictorOliveira if you are trying to pass data between Activities then you should really read my link.  it's hard to tell what you are doing though.

Comment: it's not about data, not now, but thanks for your advice, when it shows up to me this problem I will remember what you've said